# How to serve static files in forum subfolder on nginx?

Tags: php, configuration, nginx

I am trying to set up an nginx server with basically 3 different types of content:

- The main website, running on CodeIgniter
- A Q&A forum, in a subfolder `/qa` (running on Question2Answer)
- Static files (in various locations including `/qa`)

I am running into various troubles. My current config (inside the server block) is:

```
# Q2A
if ($request_uri ~* "^/qa/") {
    rewrite ^/qa/(.*)$ /qa/index.php?qa-rewrite=$1 last;
}
# CI
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
location / {
    index index.php index.html;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_cache one;
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  200 302 304 5m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  301 1h;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/site$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

This is mostly working except for these issues:

- Requests for PHP files in my application folder are being parsed/executed. Obviously since this is not going through the CI app it causes errors (variables not found etc).
- All static files inside the `qa` folder are being passes to the Q2A app instead of being served as static files

I've tried so many different things I've lost count, such as using a location block like `location ~* ^/qa/ {}` and various permutations of `try_files` but no luck. I also tried modifying [this Wordpress example on the nginx site](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress#Non-root_try_files_to_URL_redirect). Most of them just ended with `/qa/` returning a 404. Some methods have resulted in the server serving raw PHP code!

Can anyone help with the proper method to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^/qa/") {
    rewrite ^/qa/(.*)$ /qa/index.php?qa-rewrite=$1 last;
}
```

with

```
location ~ /qa/(.*)? {
    try_files $uri /qa/index.php?qa-rewrite=$1&$query_string;
}
```

also the block

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

is better to be moved inside the `/` location and converted into `try_files`

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$request_uri
}
```

if you still are having trouble please tell me.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the pages in the /qa directory are not working, apart from the directory itself, `mysite.com/qa/`. Also, I tried changing that to `location ~* ^/qa/(.*)?$` to make sure it's the entire URL and it promptd to download PHP code!

Comment: Hmm, I may have something a little wrong. Here is the original Apache rule: `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

Comment: Like I said, if I use `location ~` it's **downloading** the actual PHP code, i.e. downloading the file `/qa/index.php`. Why would that be?

Comment: because it's not passing the php code to the php engine, so it's serving the php file as an asset, did you erase the `location ~ \.php$` location ?

Comment: No I didn't remove it. My config is just like in my question but with the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

[If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). But you can use `try_files` and some location blocks to accomplish the same thing.

```
# in a `server` block
index index.php index.html;

# case sensitive version
# location ~ ^/qa/(.*)?$ {
location  ~* ^/qa/(.*)?$ {
    try_files $uri /qa/index.php?qa-rewrite=$1;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$request_uri;
}

# not sure if you even need location /, this might work
# try_files $uri /index.php?$request_uri;

# the rest of your FastCGI config stuff here
```

Comment: This doesn't work, in the qa folder it's prompting to download PHP code!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the configuration I use for my own PHP sites running nginx.

Note this is untested but it should work since it is only a slightly modified version.

Just replace the (insert) with your server values in the log and root directives.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/(insert).access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/(insert).error.log;
    root (insert);
    server_name (insert);
    rewrite ^/qa/(.*(?![\.js|\.css])[^.]+)$ /qa/index.php/$1 last;
    rewrite ^(.*(?![\.js|\.css])[^.]+)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_cache one;
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  200 302 304 5m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid  301 1h;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```